# Converting two columns of a data frame to a named vector

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, coercion

I need to convert a multi-row two-column `data.frame` to a named character vector. 
My `data.frame` would be something like:

```
dd = data.frame(crit = c("a","b","c","d"), 
                name = c("Alpha", "Beta", "Caesar", "Doris")
                )
```

and what I actually need would be:

```
whatiwant = c("a" = "Alpha",
              "b" = "Beta",
              "c" = "Caesar",
              "d" = "Doris")
```

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Use the `names` function:

```
whatyouwant <- as.character(dd$name)
names(whatyouwant) <- dd$crit
```

`as.character` is necessary, because `data.frame` and `read.table` turn characters into factors with default settings.

If you want a one-liner:

```
whatyouwant <- setNames(as.character(dd$name), dd$crit)
```

Answer (score 77):

You can also use [`deframe(x)` from the **tibble** package](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/enframe.html) for this.

```
tibble::deframe()
```

It converts the first column to names and second column to values.

Comment: Thank you John!  I am amazed that after years of using the tidyverse I still learn about functions that are so useful.  I wish I knew about this a long time ago.  I guess I'm always a student.

Comment: For anyone coming to this post asking the inverse question - *How do I convert a named vector to a two-column data frame?* - the answer is `tibble::enframe()`

Answer (score 31):

Here is a very general, easy, tidy way:

```
library(dplyr)

iris %>%
  pull(Sepal.Length, Species)
```

The first argument is the values, the second argument is the names.

Comment: Very neat. Probably will become my goto once it goes live.

Comment: should be the top answer in 2021

Answer (score 27):

You can make a vector from `dd$name`, and add names using `names()`, but you can do it all in one step with `structure()`:

```
whatiwant <- structure(as.character(dd$name), names = as.character(dd$crit))
```

Answer (score 8):

For variety, try `split` and `unlist`:

```
unlist(split(as.character(dd$name), dd$crit))
#        a        b        c        d 
#  "Alpha"   "Beta" "Caesar"  "Doris"
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that this makes duplicated names unique by appending a number to them. It's also not very efficient with big vectors.

Answer (score 3):

There's also a `magrittr` solution to this via [the exposition pipe (`%$%`)](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/exposition.html):

```
library(magrittr)

dd %$% set_names(as.character(name), crit)
```

Minor advantage over `tibble::deframe` is that one doesn't have to have exactly a two-column frame/tibble as argument (i.e., avoid a `select(value_col, name_col) %>%`).

Note that the `magrittr::set_names` versus `base::setNames` is exchangeable. I simply prefer the former since it matches `"set_(col|row)?names"`.