# Conveniently extract a named vector from data.frame using dplyr/tidy?

Tags: r, dplyr

How can we extract a *named* vector whose names come from one data.frame column and values from another, conveniently, using the pipe? (and without assigning in between)

Here is a very manual approach

```
vec <- iris %>% 
  arrange(Sepal.Length) %>% 
  pull(Sepal.Length)

names_for_vec <- iris %>% 
  arrange(Sepal.Length) %>% 
  pull(Species)


names(vec) <- names_for_vec 
names(vec)

# Named vector
vec
```

Ideally, I'd like to achieve the same result in one line

#### What I've tried

I've tried variations on the top two answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19265172/converting-two-columns-of-a-data-frame-to-a-named-vector), as well as another idea of using `"names<-"()`:

```
iris %>% 
  arrange(desc(Sepal.Length)) %>% 
  pull(Sepal.Length) %>%  
  `names<-`() # But we can't access the Species column as it was 2 pipes back..
```

Comment: Try using `setNames`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pull.data.frame` method already accepts an argument for naming. I thought this was available previously, but this might be only in `dplyr` 1.0, in which case you would need to install from the `tidyverse\dplyr` Github repo.

```r
iris %>%
  arrange(Sepal.Length) %>%
  pull(Sepal.Length, Species)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>%  arrange(Sepal.Length) %>% pull(Sepal.Length) %>%
  setNames(iris %>% arrange(Sepal.Length) %>% pull(Species))
```